# Why don't we consider interactions between the small constituent charges while calculating field of a continuous charge object

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

In continuous charge object we integrate small charges to find net field. Then why don't we consider the interaction between charges

Answer (score 0):

Due to [principal of superposition of electric field](https://brilliant.org/wiki/superposition-electric-fields/)

There it says :

> The principle of superposition states that every charge in space creates an electric field at point independent of the presence of other charges in that medium. The resultant electric field is a vector sum of the electric field due to individual charges.

So it is irrelevant to consider interaction between individual point charges when calculating the net $\vec E$ field.

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450680/superposition-principle-for-electric-fields) is a helpful link as to justifying why superposition principle.

Comment: Thanks for information.